# adding a custom key in to html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

assume we have a set of html tags like

```
<div id="slide1" class="slide"></div>
<div id="slide2" class="slide"></div>
<div id="slide3" class="slide"></div>
```

I am trying to add an extra attribute in to the div tag like `key='post'` from the hash `{"post" : ["0","1"], "get": ["0","2"], "search": ["2","1"]}` for each tags respectively.
so that it looks like,

```
<div id="slide1" class="slide" key="post"></div>
<div id="slide2" class="slide" key="get"></div>
<div id="slide3" class="slide" key="search"></div>
```

Is it possible to do that using javascript??

The code that I came up with looks like

```
for(key in hashArray){
var el = document.getElementsByID('slide' + (slideNumber));
el.setAttribute('key', key);
slideNumber++;
}
```

but im getting an error  document.getElementByID is not a function

Comment: You can add new keys, but browsers may complain that they find keys they did not expect to find. I was doing it before but at some point I had to give up on it (don't remember why) and use variables in javascript that were holding information for these ids.

Comment: I don't think browsers complain about non–standard attributes in markup provided they conform to the general rules. However, behaviour may be different (e.g. some don't create DOM properties for non-standard attributes, others do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [custom data attributes](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) [e.g. `data-key`], then you are perfectly right.

EDIT: your code will look like:

```
var slideNumber = 1;

for(key in hashArray){
    var el = document.getElementById('slide' + (slideNumber));
    el.setAttribute('data-key', key);
    slideNumber++;
}
```

[Working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/YtEpS/).

Comment: It is still showing the eror document.getElementByID is not a function

Comment: It's **getElementById**, lowercase d.

Comment: What have you initialized `slideNumber` to? If 0, it searches for `slide0`and won't find it of course - look at the fiddle I put above.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because the correct method name is `getElementById`, *singular*.

That said, your code should work. However, I recommend using `data-key` instead of `key` as the attribute name, so your HTML remains valid (valid HTML5).

Comment: WHat's the value of `slideNumber`?

Answer (score 0):

The use of non–standard attributes or properties is recommended against for the usual reasons — behaviour in different user agents is not specified, possible conflict with custom properties of other programs and future additions to standard attributes and properties and so on.

As pointed out in other answers, you can use `data-` attributes, but even they have the above issues for older browsers. In the OP, I can't see any benefit to using *setAttribute* over direct property access:

```
el['data-key'] = key;
```

(It would have been more convenient if the W3C had chosen underscore as the delimiter instead of hyphen.)

Using properties, the value can be any type whereas [*setAttribute*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-F68F082) only allows strings.

Another option is to store values in an object or array and get them by some reference (e.g. the element ID), which also allows values to be a type other than string.